# Java collections: TreeMap.size() and TreeSet.size(): O(1) or O(n)?

Tags: java, data-structures

Do [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#size%28%29) and [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#size%28%29) keep track of how many items they contain, or do they have to count them every time you call `size()`? The javadocs remain mute on the subject.

Comment: In most IDEs you can `<ctrl>+<click>` on a method to see its source.  This works for builtin classes as well.

Comment: BTW: You have about 180 questions without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/TreeMap.java.html

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/TreeSet.java.html

For future reference, the google search was "java source code treemap". (I'm not saying that to be snarky -- it's not entirely obvious that the source code would be out there for the googlin').

tl;dr version is that they keep track, so it's O(1).

Comment: It is also worth noting that the JDK comes with source code for Java SE classes.

Comment: @Dev Very good point. I always have it on my IDE's modules list, so that I can take a look at the code from within the IDE.

Comment: thanks! bonus points for pointing out the source code (I can never remember how to find that stuff)

Comment: pretty much every one of the collection classes keeps track of it's size and does not compute it each time you ask for it.

Comment: Actually, you are only linking to the source code for OpenJDK 7 and have observed an implementation specific detail. Other versions of the Java VM (from Oracle or other vendors) may implement these classes completely different.

Comment: Also of note is the google search:  java.util.TreeMap grepcode  in case you are not working in an ide for some reason.  Most major libraries are source xref'd on grepcode, and it's an invaluable tool (as is docjar)

Comment: @jarnbjo I assumed from the fact the OP linked to the Oracle javadocs that they wanted the standard Oracle implementations. I also assumed from the question that the OP understood that it's an implementation detail, rather than a part of the official spec. Rather than being pedantic about it, I gave the answer to the question I felt was being asked. Mea culpa for linking to the JDK 7 instead of 6 (though it's the same in 6).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do keep track of how many objects they contain, so calling `size()` on either yields O(1) runtime.